# Найти совпадения

Tags: php, excel, текст

Добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти верное направление для реализации моей задачи, которая заключается в следующем:

Есть 2 списка. Первый представляет собой excel-таблицу, второй - txt файл. В первом списке есть несколько параметров: город, индекс, ФИО. Во втором списке только город. Параметр город в первом и во втором списках написан по-разному: в первом - каждый город указан в своей ячейке в excel-файле (индекс и ФИО, соответственно тоже каждый в своей ячейке), во втором - все города записаны через запятую с разным регистром.

Что требуется: сравнить первый (excel-файл) и второй (txt-файл) списки, найти повторяющиеся города в них и вывести из первого списка только те строки в excel-файле (то есть город, индекс, ФИО), которые будут совпадать  без учета регистра со вторым списком.

Заранее спасибо за подсказки!

Comment: Приведите примеры данных первого и второго файла.

Comment: @fens
Excel-файл: http://image.prntscr.com/image/d98f16ebab3647eda0d3e9ca6117d779.png

Txt-файл: http://image.prntscr.com/image/4cf97b558f01410692f1f0a455949f83.png

Comment: если действительно excel тогда минимум вам нужна PHPExcel либа. Дальше explode текстовика по ',' и приведение и второго и первого списка к одному регистру через strtolower ну а потом собственно сравнение. Внимание если у вас города могут быть и с кириллическими именами тогда вместо strtolower стоит использовать mb_strtolower

Comment: Так же для сравнения после приведения обоих к одному регистру, можно воспользоваться функцией array_intersect передав в качестве первого параметра массив со значениями из первого списка, а в качестве второго массив со значениями из второго в результате получите список из первого массив элементы которого встречаются во втором.